# Javascript: how to really prove a frame is loaded? Global variables not working?

Tags: javascript

I've been fooling around with developing an IETMs interface (Interactive Electronic Technical Manual - like an interactive parts catalogue) to display the data live from an existing Access database. The idea is to be able to run this interface on a network hosted intranet with straight HTML, plain Javascript, VBScript & ActiveX objects, so that it doesn't require IIS etc to run ASP or PHP etc (I don't want to involve corporate IT for the IIS).

All is going pretty well, & I'm impressed with the setup except for a few minor things - checking if a frame is loaded, & global variables.

My setup is a HTML page hosting 5 frames with each containing an empty  (which gets the page written to it dynamically), but I need to ensure all frames are loaded before getting into the heavy stuff (which Javascript is handling brilliantly!). But I'm finding that Javascript sux at truly detecting if a frame is loaded (someone please prove me wrong!). I have all 5 frames call a function fnInitialiseIfReady(), then if I could either successfully test if all frames are loaded, or if I could globally count if this function has been called 5 times, I can proceed with confidence & call my function fnInitialise(). But unfortunately neither is working for me. :(

From tireless internet searches, I've tried the 'frames always load in order' theory, & that is simply not correct. I have set up a test with the frames calling a function passing their name as a parameter, & each time the frames load in a different order every time. It is totally random. Note: I proved this by having the first 4 frames call a certain function(which contains an alert() line showing the frame name parameter passed), & having the last frame call a different function (which contains an alert("all are loaded!") line). The "all are loaded!" does not always appear last.

I've also tried the '.frames["FrameName"].document.loaded' approach, & it ALWAYS returns 'undefined' for every frame. Am I doing something wrong here?

I've also tried the '.frames["FrameName"].window.location.href' approach & it ALWAYS returns the html filename regardless of whether that page has loaded or not, so it is not an indicator of loading completion.

I've also tried the '.frames["FrameName"].document.location' approach & it's ALWAYS the same as the '.window.location.href' approach.

Also, I'm finding Javascript will not hold global variables for me at all. I don't know if it's a combination of multiple frames & using Javascript & VBScript together, but global variables just do not hold a value at all. Local variables (within functions) are fine. Any ideas? I don't have many globals, so I'm thinking of using a cookie. A valid Solution?

BTW, the reason for also using VBScript is that it accesses the ActiveX controls by default, & being a corporate intranet app I can guarantee MSIE usage.

It's frustrating because if I can solve these 2 relatively minor issues, then I'm super impressed with the robustness of this Javascript/VBScript approach. By leveraging each of their strengths, it's crunching the data just as quickly as the VB, C#, & C++ programs I've written for this particular dataset. I'm impressed! :)

Thanks in advance,

Dave Lock.

Comment: whoa what a long question. could you be specific.

Comment: It's a shame that people are still developing IE-only corporate apps.. things like that will make IE be "required" in corporate environments forever.. (hopefully you are at least allowed to use another browser for regular browsing)

Comment: @experimentX: not really a long question, it's just a lot of background information. The question itself seems to be: "how can I use JavaScript to confirm, for sure, that all frames are loaded?"

Comment: JavaScript does in fact "hold" global variables just fine, VBScript or no.  Since you've posted no code at all, it's impossible to help discover what your mistake(s) might be.

Comment: @ ThiefMaster: I am 1 of 170,000 employees. I don't decide corporate policy on software. :)

Comment: @ Pointy: Thanks for your reply. I do suspect it may be me doing something wrong. My Javascript code runs currently at 1500 lines, I didn't think it prudent to post it all here. My global variables are declared such as...
var int_cIndentLevel = 1;
... in the beginning of the external javascript ".js" file. Yet when I try to access the var it doesn't return the set value. What code can I post to help you help me? :)

Comment: @ David Thomas: Thanks for your reply. Correct, plus my global variables don't seem to be working. :)

Comment: @ experimentX: I tried to post a comprehensive explanation so that the answers aren't what I have already tried & isn't working. The 2 questions I'm asking are in the title. :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, each frame (window) has its own 'global' context.  That's why your Javascript objects can't see each other without special effort.

Are the frames nested?  If not (i.e. they're all in the same frameset), you could try to add an `onload` event handler for each, and have those refer to some central global object.

I'm thinking you might have to add those `onload` event handlers from code (using [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), so that you could assign the same event handler to all frames.  Otherwise, I think each `onload` would run within its own (window's) global context.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Martijn. The only html in any of the 5 frames is a <DIV> tag, & the only Javascript in the 5 of them is the onload="fnInitialiseIfReady()" in the body tag. Each of the 5 frames page content is totally written dynamically at runtime by the Javascript using a .innerHTML (which works great). The Javascript is in an external .js file & the VBScript is in an external .vbs file.

Comment: I tried using "window." in front of the global vars to tie them to the window object (found that idea on the net), but that didn't work. If this is impacting having global variables, what can I do to get around it? I only have a few global variables anyway.

Comment: Yes, but what is your main page, and how are you generating _that_?  Are you using a `<frameset>` or an `<iframe>`?

Comment: @DaveLock: about the `window`: each frame has its own `window` object. That's why you can't use so-called global JS objects to communicate  between different frames.

Comment: @ Martijn: the main page (HTML) has nested <framset> in it. It's solved now anyway. Using 'top.varName' instead of just 'varName' as I was doing makes the global vars as I wanted them, so now I can just call fnInitialise() on the 5th time fnInitialiseIfReady() has been called. Thanks for your help. Dave.

Comment: @DaveLock: Could you post your final solution (`top.varName`) as an answer to your own question, and accept that?  That would be helpful to anyone stumbling on this question later on.